# Adding and Removing Write Idlestatehandler

Tags: netty

In my Netty based Http Server, i added the

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(Channel channel) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = channel.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("KeepAlive_Handler", new IdleStateHandler(readTimeout, 0, 0));
    pipeline.addLast("Timeout_Handler", new IdleStateHandler(0, writeTimeOut, 0));

    addSSLServerHandler(pipeline);
    pipeline.addLast("http-decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder(4096, 16384, 16384));
    pipeline.addLast("http-encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());

    pipeline.addLast("Reuqest_Handler", new RequestHandler());
}
```

In RequestHandler, after the Http Request is processed i.e. a Response is sent back to client i remove the "Timeout_Handler" from pipeline and channel connection remains in open state unless KeepAlive_Handler event occurred or some fatal exception is thrown.

What i am not sure is that initChannel() from ChannelInitializer is always called for every Http Request or there are some cases where it is not invoked?? This is important because i am removing the "Timeout_Handler" after every Http Request,and if initChannel() is not invoked for some Http Requests then definitely those requests would be processed without "Timeout_Handler".

Comment: `initChannel` is called whenever a new channel (connection) is created, not between requests.

Answer (score 0):

initChannel(...) is called for each new Channel which represent a connection. So no it is not called per request.

Comment: how can i make sure that for every request(including ssl-handshake) when my server reads first byte the "write-timeout handler" is added to pipeline and when request is finished(whatever response), this "write-timeout handler" is removed??? In other words, every request must have a new instance of "write-timeout handler"